# Perform a different simple custom function based on group

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I have data with three groups and would like to perform a *different* custom function on each of the three groups. Rather than write three separate functions, and calling them all separately, I'm wondering whether I can easily wrap all three into one function with a 'group' parameter.

For example, say I want the mean for group A:

```
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

iris$Group <- c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50), rep("C", 50))

f_a <- function(df){
  out <- df %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(Sepal.Length))
  return(out)
}
```

The median for group B

```
f_b <- function(df){
  out <- df %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(median = median(Sepal.Length))
  return(out)
}
```

And the standard deviation for group C

```
f_c <- function(df){
  out <- df %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(sd= sd(Sepal.Length))
  return(out)
}
```

Is there any way I can combine the above functions and run them according to a group parameter?? Like:
`fx(df, group = "A")`
Which would produce the results of the above f_a function??

Keeping in mind that in my actual use context, I can't simply group_by(group) in the original function, since the actual functions are more complex. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a `switch` inside the function to select the appropriate function to be applied based on the matching input from `group`.  This function is passed into `summarise` to apply after groupihg by 'Species'

```
fx <- function(df, group) {
           fn_selector <- switch(group,
                        A = "mean",
                        B = "median",
                       C = "sd")
          
                       
                       
             
          df %>%
             group_by(Species) %>%
             summarise(!! fn_selector :=
             match.fun(fn_selector)(Sepal.Length), .groups = 'drop')
        }
```

-testing

```
fx(iris, "A")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species     mean
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 setosa      5.01
#2 versicolor  5.94
#3 virginica   6.59
 
fx(iris, "B")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    median
#  <fct>       <dbl>
#1 setosa        5  
#2 versicolor    5.9
#3 virginica     6.5

fx(iris, "C")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species       sd
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 setosa     0.352
#2 versicolor 0.516
#3 virginica  0.636
```

Comment: This is helpful in it's own right but not exactly what i'm looking for. I really want to do completely different functions for each group. Like the three functions above (f_a, f_b, f_c), can they be combined into one larger function?? Potentially using if else??

Comment: @Lachlan Sorry, Do you need a `switch` function or are you applying three functions based on the 'group' column already created?

Comment: @Lachlan can you please check if the update is what you are looking for.  I was thinking that you wanted to pass argument in group_by.   Sorry, it is my mistake.

Comment: This is the part I need to clarify in my question. I didn't ask outright since I thought a simpler example might solve it (probably wrong there). Each df I feed into this function only has one group. So I want to perform one of three functions, depending on which group the df contains (A, B or C). I will clarify my question now

Comment: @Lachlan Yes, then the update should work.  Please check the output I showed

Comment: @Lachlan We don't need to change the data by creating a group column.  It is more easier with `switch`

Comment: Yes, thank you for introducing me to switch -  it is the function I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the point of having `group` column in the dataset. When we pass `group = "A"` in the function this has got nothing to do with `group` column that was created.

Instead of passing `group = "A"` in the function and then mapping `A` to some function you can directly pass the function that you want to apply.

```
library(dplyr)

f_a <- function(df, fn){
  out <- df %>% 
          group_by(Species) %>% 
          summarise(out = fn(Sepal.Length))
  return(out)
}

f_a(iris, mean)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species      out
#* <fct>      <dbl>
#1 setosa      5.01
#2 versicolor  5.94
#3 virginica   6.59

f_a(iris, median)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species      out
#* <fct>      <dbl>
#1 setosa       5  
#2 versicolor   5.9
#3 virginica    6.5
```

Comment: I think I oversimplified my question and made it too vague. In my real data, each distinct dataset has a column with either A, B or C. And depending on that value, I want to use a different function. So I read in the dataframe, and then apply function A if the data is group A, function B if the data is group B etc. I'm new to writing functions so doing intricate things like this is a bit beyond me